# Rate of convergence of the logistic map

Tags: recurrence-relations, rate-of-convergence

Given the logistic map $x_{n+1} = r x_n(1-x_n)$, it is well-known that if $0 \le r\le 1$, then $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} x_n = 0$ regardless of the value of $x_0\in(0,1)$.  What is the asymptotic rate of convergence to zero in this case, and why?  In other words, how fast does it go to zero?  Is $x_n = O(x_0^n)$?

This is a simpler version of what I actually want, which is the asymptotic rate of convergence, for constant $z\in(0,1/2]$, of the logistic map $x_{n+1} = z^2 x_n(\frac{2}{z}-x_n)$.

Comment: @achillehui thanks.  For $r=1$, where are you getting the $O(\log n)$ term from?

Comment: @achillehui Just to be pedantic, that seems like circular logic:  after all, the behavior of $x_n$ as $1/n$ is only clear to me if we assume it to be the case and then we get the remainder as $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{k}$, but without that assumption, maybe $x_n = 1/\sqrt{n}$ and then the remainder is $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} \approx \sqrt{n}$.

Comment: @achillehui I agree that $\frac{1}{x_n} \ge \frac{1}{x_0} + n$, but this only implies a _lower bound_ of $\sim \frac{1}{x_0} + n + \log n$, not an upper bound:  $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{x_k}{1-x_k} \gtrsim \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{k} \approx \log n$.